# all Locust tests results suddenly turned to all 0

Tags: python, locust

everyone
i am new to locust and i found such thing which really confused me

i use different usernames and passwords to log in the site,and i call my "log in" function under on_start funtion,

but when i started my locust script, i found at first i can see everything worked well, all my usernames and passwords were used to log in and i could see all these requests detailed info like their "median","average",but suddenly i saw all these numbers turened to 0 like following link,

i found only all "log in" requests had such problem, all other requests showed correctly, so i wonder why that happened?thank u in advance
[resultpic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIkXL.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you start Locust, any requests that happen while in startup are reset once all locusts are hatched.

So in this case it looks like your login attempts happen before locust is "ready" to actually begin counting requests, given that they are login attempts.